# Storage system for student marks program

Tags: java

Im trying to make a marks storing program for my personal use, but i find problems when deciding how to store the marks. What i need is tsomething like this

Subject 1

----1(semesters)

------mark1

------mark2

------mark3

----2

------mark1

------mark2

----3

------mark1

I was thinking of using a HashMap or a local database, but the problem starts when some of the marks inside the same semester can be equal and i need to be able to delete or edit one of them.

BTW i feel more confident with java than other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each of the marks a unique key. use a `HashMap` for that.

```
HashMap<String, String> marks = new HashMap<>();

marks.put("date_of_mark_given", mark);
```

Here is how to create unique keys deterministically based on dates.

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/ddThh:MM:ss");
final UUID key = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(sdf.format(new Date()).getBytes());
final HashMap<UUID, String> marks = new HashMap<>();
marks.put(key, mark);
```

This is the best way to create keys that are not just plain `String` but can be recreated very easily and you never have to worry about collisions.

If the `Date` isn't unique enough, just add some other uniquely identifying information.

You should also make your *mark* into a real class, preferably and `Enum`.

Comment: Instead of using the date, maybe i will generate an id. Cause two or more marks can be given the same day, but thnks for answering!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe MongoDB will be useful for you?